Password manager suggestion/autofill in Android Webview
My Android app is embedding a web login page into a webview.
When the login textbox is clicked, the username saved in the Android password manager has always been suggested on the top part of the keyboard.
Starting from today no suggestion comes up on the keyboard, even though I haven't changed anything, neither in the app nor in the password manager entries.
I wonder if anything has changed on the Android system side with a recent update? Or what else could have happened?
Is anyone experiencing something similar?

If the login is running in a webview, its likely using the default browsers password manager. Check that the default browser is still the same on the device app settings. Also make sure that no browser data has been deleted e.g autofill, username and password related data.

Integrate Credential Manager with autofill (android.com) credentials v1.5.2 (android.com)

It seems like a WebView's autofill problem, here are some of the suggestions:
1.) check if the WebView configurations was not changed, like the autofill being disabled in the WebView settings.
2.) check if the device's settings related to autofill or password management was changed.
3.) sometimes, clearing the WebView cache can solve the problem.
4.) try other devices to isolate the issue
5.) check if your WebView components are up to date.

I am not sure but, I hope that configuration might do the job.
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
webView.settings.setSaveFormData(true) 
webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN)

Use WebView debugger to check if something in the WebView is blocking password suggestions.
WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)

